# Laravel Auth::attempt Expiring session

Tags: session, authentication, laravel

I have come across a very strange problem where after login via `Auth::attempt()` the session expires.

I am using following code

```
Route::post('user/auth', function(){

    if (Auth::attempt(array('email' => 'email@yahoo.com', 'password' => 'some password','user_status'=>'active')))
    {
        $userId = Auth::id();
    }

});
```

Every time I run this call `user/auth`, the session values are destroyed and new token is set by laravel. This is happening on hosting server. While on my local computer it is working fine.

Please help I have invested 2 days finding the problem.

I have set links for explaining:--

On the following link I am using Auth::attempt while also displaying all of the session variables. Please notice the _token. This is the page where my all previously set session variables are being destroyed.

http://behungry.co.in/set/session

On following page I am just calling Session::all() to display all the sessions. PLease check the _token variable here. They both are different. While I am expecting them to be same and persist the sessions.

http://behungry.co.in/get/sessions

FOLLOWING IS MY APP/CONFIG/SESSION FILE'S CONTENT

```
'driver' => 'database',
'lifetime' => 120,
'expire_on_close' => false,
'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
'connection' => null,
'table' => 'sessions',
'lottery' => array(2, 100),
'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
'path' => '/',
'domain' => '',
'secure' => false,
```

Sessions are working fine on rest of the website. I have tried both file and database drivers. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show your `app/config/session.php` file.

Comment: @TheAlpha this is my session config files content. Please note sessions are working fine on rest of the site. Only the session variables set before Auth::attempt are being destroyed.                   return array(

 
 'driver' => 'database',
 
 'lifetime' => 120,

 'expire_on_close' => false,

 'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
 

 'connection' => null,

 
 'table' => 'sessions',

 
 'lottery' => array(2, 100),

 
 'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

 'path' => '/',

 
 'domain' => '',
 

 'secure' => false,

Answer (score 0):

Can you change domain with

```
'domain' => null,
```

I explaned in there https://stackoverflow.com/a/28774751/2438520